# jQuery animation detect if animating?

Tags: jquery

Is their a way to detect if an element is animating or detect if values of an element is changing?

Because I need to trigger a function if an element is animating. Not onComplete of animate.

Answer (score 24):

**The following returns true when the selected element is animating:**

```
var isAnimating = $("#someid").is(':animated');
```

**More detail:**

http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/
and/or
http://api.jquery.com/animate/
**step:** A function to be called after each step of the animation.

Comment: Andy please can I just clarify my understanding of pseudo-selector :animated. The behaviour that I am seeing is that once the element has started to be animated is(:animated) is true even when the element has been returned to it's starting point. I am therefore using step to detect when an animation has reached it's animated position. Is there a way to toggle the pseudo selector on and off?

Comment: @codepuppy this is strange, i made a test here: http://jsfiddle.net/aPk3y/1/ and it returns the correct value. I don't think there's an easy way to manipulate :animated directly.

Comment: Andy thanks for this example. OK so I can see it works for you. Therefore I must be making a mistake somewhere. I will go back and review my test again.

Comment: @codepuppy maybe you could show some of your code or create a jsfiddle  or even link to your page, then i could have a look at it.

Comment: Great and quick simple answer!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be adding a global boolean that gets set to `true` as soon as the animation starts. Then you add a callback function to the animation that sets it to `false` as it finishes.

```
var running = false;

$('#start').click(function(){

    running = true;

    $('#target').animate({opacity: 0.5},'slow',function(){

        running = false;

    });

});
```

Edit: Oh I guess there's a selector for it.

Comment: If you use this method, take notice of how you use it because in unique situations it could cause a race condition. Example: `1. Click start button (1) -- running = true -- t=0ms` `2. Click start button (2) -- running = true -- t=200ms` `3. Animation (1) finishes -- running = false -- t=600ms` `4. Animation (2) running -- running = false -- 600ms < t < 800ms` `5. Animation (2) finishes -- running = false -- t=800ms`