# Animate continuously with one press

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I use this to scroll animate a page.

```
if (e.keyCode == 38)  
$('div').animate({scrollTop:"-=50"},'5000', 'linear')
if (e.keyCode == 40)  
$('div').animate({scrollTop:"+=50"},'5000', 'linear')
```

but I have to press and hold up or down arrow key to continuously animate. How can I make it to start animation on one press then increase speed when the same key (up or down) is pressed again

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992626/jquery-animation-detect-if-animating), you can add another if clause that detects if it is animating or not. If it is animating, stop the current animation and start another with a faster speed.

I think an integer regarding how many times it has been animated would be nice, as the speed could be 50*THAT_INTEGER.