# jQuery slider not working. Pressing links does nothing

Tags: jquery, css, slider

Could anyone please explain why the following jQuery slider is not working? Each of my four website pages is contained within the divs with the ids 'target1', 'target2' etc. I was hoping that when you press the links in #headingLogoBar, the pages would slide in (without moving the #headinglogobar) from the side.

(Also, how do I make it so you can only activate one link at a time i.e. not allow one animation to activate whilst another is activated).

I want my website to essentially have the same functionality as: 
http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/rs2QK/

CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }

    #wrapper {
        width:960px;
        height: 630px;
        margin:0 auto;
        font-family: Arial;
        color: #555;
        background-color: white;
        vertical-align: middle;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        }

    div.forMovingPanel {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display:none;
        }
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="headingLogoBar">
               <ul>
                    <li id="menuDisplayedHome"><a href="#target1" class="forMovingpanel">HOME</li>
                    <li id="menuDisplayedAbout"><a href="#target2" class="forMovingpanel">ABOUT</a></li>        
                    <li id="menuDisplayedPortfolio"><a href="#target3" class="forMovingpanel">PORTFOLIO</a></li>    
                    <li id="menuDisplayedContact"><a href="#target4" class="forMovingpanel">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="forMovingPanel" id="target1"></div>
        <div class="forMovingPanel" id="target2"></div>
        <div class="forMovingPanel" id="target3"></div>
        <div class="forMovingPanel" id="target4"></div>

    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>


        jQuery(function($) {

$('a.forMovingPanel').click(function() {
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
        $other = $target.siblings('.active');

    if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
        $other.each(function(index, self) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                left: $this.width()
            }, 500);
        });

        $target.addClass('active').show().css({
            left: -($target.width())
        }).animate({
            left: 0
        }, 500);
    }
});

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a simple typo in your code.

The `click event` has the selector `forMovingPanel`, but your `a element` has the class `forMovingpanel` (one time the p of panel is upper-case and the other not).

And for your animation check have a look at one of these links:

- [jQuery animation detect if animating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992626/jquery-animation-detect-if-animating)
- [How do I find out with jQuery if an element is being animated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724911/how-do-i-find-out-with-jquery-if-an-element-is-being-animated)